# PHP Form on WordPress (4.6.1) site

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

forgive me if is a basic question...

I am working on setting up a form on our new hosted Wordpress site - currently hosted inhouse on IIS/PHP/Wordpress server (I am not JR - but this stuff escapes me and would really like to figure it out!! I hate not knowing)

The OP that made the form / got it working is no longer around and I am sure there is a better way but this is what I have - a request form.

When I load the required files in the same path - copy the code from the WP page and paste it in the new Wordpress page - it loads without formating, the pick box doesnt look right and when I submit the form - I get these below PHP file errors.  I can open the path in my browser and it exists - I see the class.GA_Parse.php file)

I checked execustion rights on the scripts - its set to execute - apart from that I dont know why it cant fine the files and that include_path I dont see via my hosting companys dir structure via FTP.

Any help would put me forever in your debt, I hope to be able to return the help, this site looks amazing!

Cheers,

Warning: require(/gaparser/class.GA_Parse.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/comany/public_html/stage/forms/getfreetrial_v3.php on line 4

Warning: require(/gaparser/class.GA_Parse.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/company/public_html/stage/forms/getfreetrial_v3.php on line 4

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/gaparser/class.GA_Parse.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/company/public_html/stage/forms/getfreetrial_v3.php on line 4

Comment: You cant expect people to help without a single line of code or tell us what form you are using. You need to post more information than that.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow :-) please look at [ask]

Answer (score 0):

PHP will load pages based on the disk location, not the URL. This means it's starting in the server's root `/` directory, not in `/home/company/public_html/stage/forms`.  When including a file, either you have to use a relative link:

```
require('./gaparser/class.GA_Parse.php'); // starts in the same directory as the file
```

Or use PHP's server variable to get the document root:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/gaparser/class.GA_Parse.php');
```

The paths may need to be tweaked depending on where the file actually is.